Animation scroll with sticky elements
I have a layout that includes full width image and below 2 columns with text.

In the beginning I would like to hide text columns, so it is something like an image cover the whole text in the viewport.

When you start scrolling the image moves up (like a normal scroll) and then uncovers the "fixed" to the top left column.


Step 1.1
Step 1.2

When I scroll enough, I have a gap between the image and the left column, I would like to lock the position of the image and when I scroll more, then it will appearing scrolling the right column up.
The right column will be moved up as long as reach it the original position.

Step 2
Step 3

After reaching the position, then it will start in the normal scroll.

I tried a few methods with sticky, fixed positions, but I stuck with that.
Any help here?
https://codepen.io/Matteokr/pen/rNgedKL


.section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.text-left {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.text-right {
  background: lightgreen;
  // margin-top: 1000px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row wrapper">
      <div class="col-6 text text-left">
        <h2>TEXT 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor purus sit amet dapibus eleifend. Sed vel erat quis leo vehicula ultrices. Pellentesque augue ipsum, molestie sed quam at, vestibulum viverra nisi. Nunc efficitur lorem
          sed lacus pellentesque facilisis. Nullam commodo, sapien ultrices dapibus interdum, lorem quam dictum risus, a commodo purus nisl quis mi. Integer vestibulum aliquet porttitor. Vestibulum auctor neque vitae ipsum varius dignissim. Nunc quis
          augue vel sapien auctor ultricies. Maecenas varius libero iaculis neque placerat, sit amet hendrerit purus condimentum. Aenean fringilla eros ac interdum commodo. Morbi scelerisque lorem ut nisl ornare, mattis efficitur sem aliquam. In hendrerit
          tempus lectus, eu tincidunt tellus volutpat in.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text text-right">
        <h2>TEXT 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor purus sit amet dapibus eleifend. Sed vel erat quis leo vehicula ultrices. Pellentesque augue ipsum, molestie sed quam at, vestibulum viverra nisi. Nunc efficitur lorem
          sed lacus pellentesque facilisis. Nullam commodo, sapien ultrices dapibus interdum, lorem quam dictum risus, a commodo purus nisl quis mi. Integer vestibulum aliquet porttitor. Vestibulum auctor neque vitae ipsum varius dignissim. Nunc quis
          augue vel sapien auctor ultricies. Maecenas varius libero iaculis neque placerat, sit amet hendrerit purus condimentum. Aenean fringilla eros ac interdum commodo. Morbi scelerisque lorem ut nisl ornare, mattis efficitur sem aliquam. In hendrerit
          tempus lectus, eu tincidunt tellus volutpat in.</p>
        <p>Aenean ac nunc rutrum, sagittis dui pellentesque, malesuada lorem. Sed sed bibendum lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam eu neque neque. Fusce quis enim interdum, efficitur arcu at,
          dignissim turpis. Quisque bibendum risus nec tempus congue. Ut at libero ut ipsum venenatis dignissim id non purus. Vestibulum et bibendum dui, a sollicitudin lectus. Morbi mollis auctor risus at sodales.</p>
        <p>Nullam elit velit, consectetur et pretium eget, dapibus in odio. Integer nec dignissim massa. Duis convallis tellus eu molestie ornare. Quisque dapibus ipsum et euismod laoreet. Suspendisse vulputate dui quis lacinia vehicula. Integer ac commodo
          ligula. Pellentesque at vehicula ligula. Mauris nec luctus nunc, id pharetra mauris. Aenean rhoncus orci quam, sit amet elementum tortor lobortis quis. Ut in scelerisque nisl.</p>
        <p>Nullam elit velit, consectetur et pretium eget, dapibus in odio. Integer nec dignissim massa. Duis convallis tellus eu molestie ornare. Quisque dapibus ipsum et euismod laoreet. Suspendisse vulputate dui quis lacinia vehicula. Integer ac commodo
          ligula. Pellentesque at vehicula ligula. Mauris nec luctus nunc, id pharetra mauris. Aenean rhoncus orci quam, sit amet elementum tortor lobortis quis. Ut in scelerisque nisl.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

I added a snippet.

I think I have a solution, if I understand your goal correctly. I ended up changing the CSS to not use Bootstrap, as I am not that familiar with it, and I wanted to make sure there wasn't any unknown CSS preventing me from achieving the correct outcome.
Although I have a boilerplate section—that I use standard in my projects—I recommend looking through it. One of the main things it the position and the box-sizing. If you don't understand why I changed those, let me know and I can explain.
The main thing that allows it to work in my example was changing the HTML structure so that the image and the two text containers are all siblings. This allows for the position: sticky; to work as intended on the separate elements, since they are in the same scroll context.
Here's a quick rundown of what I did:

HTML Structure Change:



Made the image and text sections direct siblings


CSS Adjustments:



Made the first text section position: sticky; with the bottom set to 0. This allows the section to lock to stay under the image, while also staying in a fixed position.




Made the first text section the height of the viewport (including a calc function for spacing). This allows for the parent of the text in this section to remain at the top of the screen, rather than the bottom.



Forked CodePen with Changes


/* Begin Boilerplate */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: system-ui, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

body {
  min-height: 100svh;
  background-color: rgb(250 250 250);
}

img {
  font-style: italic;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  shape-margin: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: ui-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  hanging-punctuation: first last;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-wrap: balance;
  color: rgb(7 7 7);
}

h1,
h2 {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h3,
h4 {
  padding-bottom: 0.375rem;
}

h5,
h6 {
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}

h1:last-child,
h2:last-child,
h3:last-child,
h4:last-child,
h5:last-child,
h6:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

button,
a,
p {
  text-wrap: pretty;
}

p {
  max-width: 75ch;
  color: rgb(7 7 7 / 0.7);
}

address {
  font-style: unset;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0);
  }

  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    color: rgb(250 250 250);
  }

  p {
    color: rgb(250 250 250 / 0.7);
  }

  @media (pointer: fine) {
    body {
      background-color: rgb(10 10 10);
    }
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
  [data-parallax] {
    transform: none !important;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  :has(:target) {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 3.5rem;
  }
}
/* End Boilerplate */

/* Begin Page Styles */
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}

.z-10 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.inset-x-0 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.top-0 {
  top: 0;
}

.bottom-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.h-\[calc\(100dvh-1\.5rem\)\] {
  height: calc(100dvh - 1.5rem);
}

.w-\[calc\(50\%-1\.5rem\)\] {
  width: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
}

.mt-1\/2 {
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.plx-4 {
  padding-inline: 1rem;
}

.ply-3 {
  padding-block: 0.75rem;
}

.bg-yellow-50 {
  background-color: rgb(254 252 232);
}

.bg-green-50 {
  background-color: rgb(240 253 244);
}
/* End Page Styles */
<section>
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x600" alt="" class="z-10" />

  <div class="sticky bottom-0 inline-block h-[calc(100dvh-1.5rem)] w-[calc(50%-1.5rem)] plx-4 ply-3">
    <div class="plx-4 ply-3 bg-yellow-50">
      <h2>TEXT 1</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor purus sit amet dapibus eleifend. Sed vel erat quis leo vehicula ultrices. Pellentesque augue ipsum, molestie sed quam at, vestibulum viverra nisi. Nunc efficitur lorem sed lacus pellentesque facilisis. Nullam commodo, sapien ultrices dapibus interdum, lorem quam dictum risus, a commodo purus nisl quis mi. Integer vestibulum aliquet porttitor. Vestibulum auctor neque vitae ipsum varius dignissim. Nunc quis augue vel sapien auctor ultricies. Maecenas varius libero iaculis neque placerat, sit amet hendrerit purus condimentum. Aenean fringilla eros ac interdum commodo. Morbi scelerisque lorem ut nisl ornare, mattis efficitur sem aliquam. In hendrerit tempus lectus, eu tincidunt tellus volutpat in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='inline-block w-[calc(50%-1.5rem)] mt-1/2'>
    <div class="plx-4 ply-3 bg-green-50">
      <h2>TEXT 2</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor purus sit amet dapibus eleifend. Sed vel erat quis leo vehicula ultrices. Pellentesque augue ipsum, molestie sed quam at, vestibulum viverra nisi. Nunc efficitur lorem sed lacus pellentesque facilisis. Nullam commodo, sapien ultrices dapibus interdum, lorem quam dictum risus, a commodo purus nisl quis mi. Integer vestibulum aliquet porttitor. Vestibulum auctor neque vitae ipsum varius dignissim. Nunc quis augue vel sapien auctor ultricies. Maecenas varius libero iaculis neque placerat, sit amet hendrerit purus condimentum. Aenean fringilla eros ac interdum commodo. Morbi scelerisque lorem ut nisl ornare, mattis efficitur sem aliquam. In hendrerit tempus lectus, eu tincidunt tellus volutpat in.</p>
      <br>

      <p>Aenean ac nunc rutrum, sagittis dui pellentesque, malesuada lorem. Sed sed bibendum lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam eu neque neque. Fusce quis enim interdum, efficitur arcu at, dignissim turpis. Quisque bibendum risus nec tempus congue. Ut at libero ut ipsum venenatis dignissim id non purus. Vestibulum et bibendum dui, a sollicitudin lectus. Morbi mollis auctor risus at sodales.</p>
      <br>

      <p>Nullam elit velit, consectetur et pretium eget, dapibus in odio. Integer nec dignissim massa. Duis convallis tellus eu molestie ornare. Quisque dapibus ipsum et euismod laoreet. Suspendisse vulputate dui quis lacinia vehicula. Integer ac commodo ligula. Pellentesque at vehicula ligula. Mauris nec luctus nunc, id pharetra mauris. Aenean rhoncus orci quam, sit amet elementum tortor lobortis quis. Ut in scelerisque nisl.</p>
      <br>

      <p>Nullam elit velit, consectetur et pretium eget, dapibus in odio. Integer nec dignissim massa. Duis convallis tellus eu molestie ornare. Quisque dapibus ipsum et euismod laoreet. Suspendisse vulputate dui quis lacinia vehicula. Integer ac commodo ligula. Pellentesque at vehicula ligula. Mauris nec luctus nunc, id pharetra mauris. Aenean rhoncus orci quam, sit amet elementum tortor lobortis quis. Ut in scelerisque nisl.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



I hope this helps!
